# Magmi Datapump api with configurable product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magmi

Im trying to create configurable product with datapump api. I can able to create simple product. But im not able to create/link with configurable product. Here is my data array. Am I missing something?

```
Array(['type'] => 'simple',['sku'] => 'A001-2',['price'] => 10,['color'] => 'Blue',['qty'] => 100,['is_in_stock'] => 1,['name'] => 'A001-2',['tax_class_id'] => 1,['store'] => 'admin',)

Array(['type'] => 'simple',['sku'] => 'A001-1',['price'] => 10,['color'] => 'Indigo',['qty'] => 100,['is_in_stock'] => 1,['name'] => A001-1,['tax_class_id'] => 1,['store'] => admin,)

Array(['type'] => 'configurable', ['sku'] => 'A001',['name'] => 'TREAD JEANS',['description'] => 'Latest Edition of gunshot jeans',['price'] => 55.5,['simples_skus'] => 'A001-2,A001-1',['configurable_attributes'] => 'color',['qty'] => 100,['is_in_stock'] => 1,['tax_class_id'] => 1,)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are missing the mandatory `attribute_set` data.   Try defining an attribute set for your items and reimporting.

Comment: If we dont set attribute_set, magmi takes as "default".

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution myself. Since im not using csv files to import, I had to remove Magmi_CSVDataSource from "plugins.conf" file. Now my data source is look like this

```
[PLUGINS_DATASOURCES]
class = ""
```

Previously it was like this

```
[PLUGINS_DATASOURCES]
class = "Magmi_CSVDataSource"
```

This worked for me. Now I can import configurable products using datapump.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have achieved it modifying `plugins.conf`. You can do it without it's modification also. Here is one sample code:

```
<?php
// assuming that your script file is located in magmi/integration/datapump/product.php,
// include "magmi_defs.php" , once done, you will be able to use any magmi includes without specific path.
require_once("../../inc/magmi_defs.php");
//Datapump include
require_once("../inc/magmi_datapump.php");

// create a Product import Datapump using Magmi_DatapumpFactory
$dp=Magmi_DataPumpFactory::getDataPumpInstance("productimport");

$dp->beginImportSession("default","create");
$newProductData = array(
    'type'          => 'simple',
    'sku'           => "A001-2",
    'qty'           => 1000,
    'color'         => 'Blue',
    'price'         => 10,
    'name'          => 'A001-2',
    'tax_class_id'  => 1,
    'is_in_stock'   => 1,
    'store'         => 'admin'
);
$dp->ingest($newProductData);

$newProductData = array(
    'type'          => 'simple',
    'sku'           => "A001-1",
    'qty'           => 1000,
    'color'         => 'Indigo',
    'price'         => 10,
    'name'          => 'A001-1',
    'tax_class_id'  => 1,
    'is_in_stock'   => 1,
    'store'         => 'admin'
);
$dp->ingest($newProductData);

$newProductData = array(
    'type'          => 'configurable',
    'sku'           => "A001",
    'qty'           => 1000,
    'price'         => 10,
    'simples_skus'  => 'A001-2,A001-1',
    'configurable_attributes' => 'color',
    'name'          => 'TREAD JEANS',
    'tax_class_id'  => 1,
    'is_in_stock'   => 1,
    'store'         => 'admin'
);
$dp->ingest($newProductData);
$dp->endImportSession();
?>
```

Do not forget to enable `Configurable Item processor` using magmi UI.